# error: exam_id does not have a default value

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Buenas gentem tengo un problema a la hora de insertar los datos de mi formulario, y es lo siguiente:

La migracion preguntas, dispone de 2 llaves foraneas, las cuales son `exam_id` y `category_id` ademas de otros campos (`description`,`iframe`,`image`). El detalle aqui es, cuando deseo insertar los campos `exam_id` y `category_id`, me generan un error de que los campos no pueden ser nulos.

Mi migracion Question:

```
Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('exam_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');

        $table->text('description');
        $table->text('iframe');
        $table->text('image')->nullable();
        $table->integer('order')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('exam_id')->references('id')->on('exams')
            ->onDelete('cascade')
            ->onUpdate('cascade');

        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')
            ->onDelete('cascade')
            ->onUpdate('cascade');
    });
```

Y en el modelo tengo las siguientes relaciones...

Question Model

```
class Question extends Model{

     protected $fillable = [
         'exam_id', 'category_id' ,'description', 'iframe', 'image',
     ];

     protected $guarded = [];

     public function exam(){
         return $this->belongsTo(Exam::class);
     }

     public function category(){
         return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
     }
}
```

Y en mi metodo store tengo lo siguiente:

```
public function store(Request $request){
        $questions = Question::create($request->all());

        $questions->category()->attach($request->get('category'));

        return view('question.create', compact( 'questions'));
    }
```

Y cuando intento insertar estos datos, tengo el siguiente problema[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**UPDATE 1**:

Agrego las tablas con la cuales se hacen la relacion: la primera es

Exams

```
Schema::create('exams', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');

        $table->string('title',250);
        $table->text('description');
        $table->integer('score');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
```

Y su modelo (con su respectiva relacion) es:

```
class Exam extends Model{
protected $fillable = [
    'user_id', 'title', 'description', 'score'
];

protected $guarded = [];
/**
 * Nota esta es una relacion de 1 a N
 * 1 usuario puede tener muchos examenes
 */

public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function questions(){
    return $this->hasMany(Question::class);
 }
}
```

En la tabla categorias, tengo lo siguiente:

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name', 250);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Y el modelo donde hago la relacion:

```
class Category extends Model{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];

    public function questions(){
        return $this->hasMany(Question::class);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**:

Estuve revisando la relacion que tenia antes con la consola de tinker y esta insertaba los datos a la db correctamente. Lo intente con algunos datos y este fue el resultado.

Para la consola tinker agregue datos como estos:

```
>>> $question = Question::Create(['exam_id' => 1, 'category_id' => 1, 'description' => '¿Capital de mexico?', 'iframe' => 'algo nomas de prueba']);
=> App\Question {#4129
     exam_id: 1,
     category_id: 1,
     description: "¿Capital de mexico?",
     iframe: "algo nomas de prueba",
     updated_at: "2020-08-06 06:45:50",
     created_at: "2020-08-06 06:45:50",
     id: 1,
   }
>>> $question = Question::Create(['exam_id' => 1, 'category_id' => 2, 'description' => '¿Capital de Rusia?', 'iframe' => 'algo nomas de prueba']);
=> App\Question {#4100
     exam_id: 1,
     category_id: 2,
     description: "¿Capital de Rusia?",
     iframe: "algo nomas de prueba",
     updated_at: "2020-08-06 06:54:39",
     created_at: "2020-08-06 06:54:39",
     id: 2,
   }
>>> $question = Question::Create(['exam_id' => 4, 'category_id' => 1, 'description' => '¿Hoy es viernes, loremp ipsu?', 'iframe' => 'algo nomas de prueba']);
=> App\Question {#4133
     exam_id: 4,
     category_id: 1,
     description: "¿Hoy es viernes, loremp ipsu?",
     iframe: "algo nomas de prueba",
     updated_at: "2020-08-06 06:58:18",
     created_at: "2020-08-06 06:58:18",
     id: 3,
   }
```

Y se insertan correctamente en las tablas correspondientes, con los id correspondientes.

```
+----+---------+----------------+--------------------------------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | user_id | title          | description                    | score | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+---------+----------------+--------------------------------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |       1 | Primer examen  | Examen de testing              |   100 | 2020-07-31 05:26:31 | 2020-07-31 05:26:31 |
|  4 |       1 | Segundo examen | Descripcion del segundo examen |   100 | 2020-08-04 21:10:18 | 2020-08-04 21:10:18 |
+----+---------+----------------+--------------------------------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+

 select * from questions;
+----+---------+-------------+-------------------------------+----------------------+-------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | exam_id | category_id | description                   | iframe               | image | order | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+---------+-------------+-------------------------------+----------------------+-------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |       1 |           1 | ¿Capital de mexico?           | algo nomas de prueba | NULL  |  NULL | 2020-08-06 06:45:50 | 2020-08-06 06:45:50 |
|  2 |       1 |           2 | ¿Capital de Rusia?            | algo nomas de prueba | NULL  |  NULL | 2020-08-06 06:54:39 | 2020-08-06 06:54:39 |
|  3 |       4 |           1 | ¿Hoy es viernes, loremp ipsu? | algo nomas de prueba | NULL  |  NULL | 2020-08-06 06:58:18 | 2020-08-06 06:58:18 |
+----+---------+-------------+-------------------------------+----------------------+-------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Tambien he intentado guardar los datos con los metodos `attach()` y `associate()` que comenta recomienda laravel en su documentacion.

Intentando de esta manera:

```
 public function store(QuestionStoreRequest $request){
        $questions = Question::create($request->all());
        $questions->exam()->attach($request->get('exam_id'));
        $questions->category()->attach($request->get('category_id'));

        $questions->save();

        return view('question.create');
    }
```

Y tambien con el metodo `associate()` de esta otra forma:

```
public function store(QuestionStoreRequest $request){
        $questions = Question::create($request->all());
        $questions->exam()->associate($exams);
        $questions->category()->associate($category);

        $questions->save();

        return view('question.create');
    }
```

Sin resultado alguno.

Comment: Lo estás haciendo mal, si vas a trabajar con una relación muchos a muchos el método de eloquent que se usa es `belongsToMany()`, te redacto una respuesta

Comment: Muchas preguntas pueden pertenecer a 1 examen. Y por lo que entendí cuando leí la doc de laravel, se hace con el método `belongsTo ()` al igual que con categorías, las preguntas pueden pertenecer a una categoria.

Comment: Entonces estas empleado la relación incorrecta, ¿es una relación de 1 a muchos o de muchos a muchos? por que si es la primera se usa `hasMany y belongsTo` y se es la segunda es `belongsToMany`

Comment: Estamos hablando entonces de una relación de muchos a muchos ? con su respectiva tabla pivote cierto?

Comment: Para exam es 1 a muchos (un examen puede tener muchas preguntas) y para categoría es igual, creo (una categoría puede tener muchas preguntas). Igual, podrías redactar el ejemplo, porque ando medio perdido en ello

Comment: Si, agrego las tablas de categoría y examen a la pregunta

Comment: Entonces tenemos 3 tablas examen, categoria y questions que será la tabla pivote y entonces si estamos hablando de una relación muchos a muchos cierto? para proceder con el ejemplo

Comment: Creo que si, ya agregue los datos faltantes en la pregunta, para dar una idea mejor del problema planteado.

Comment: Yo sigo sin entender por que tratas de hacer 2 attach cuando con uno puedes guardar tanto el id del examen como el de la categoria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un escenario de muchos a muchos con las siguientes entidades:

- exams
- categories
- questions

Observaciones:

- No requerimos de forma inicial un modelo para la entidad intermedia (*la tabla pivote*) y de ser así me parece deberías [leer a detalle la doc.](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models) para conocer el modo recomendado de crear un modelo para dicha entidad
- Declararemos las relaciones que vinculan a las entidades (Exam y Category) con dicha tabla intermedia
- La relación que debes usar se llama [`belongsToMany`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) que es la que nos sirve en una relación de *muchos a muchos*

Una vez tratado eso entonces procedemos a declarar la lógica de los 2 modelos:

Modelo **Exams**

```
class Exam extends Model 
{
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'questions', 'exam_id', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

Modelo **Category**

```
class Category extends Model 
{
    public function exams()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Examn::class, 'questions', 'category_id', 'exam_id');
    }
}
```

Desde el segundo hasta el 4to. parámetro no son obligatorios, pero los coloqué para que conozcas donde irían los valores [**revisa la sección Model Structure en especial**](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many), y también recomiendo leas sobre las [**convenciones de Eloquent**](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions)

Entonces ahora para el tema de los registros, lo hacemos del modo siguiente:

```
$categoriaId = Category::findOrFail(1);
$idExam      = Exam::findOrFail(2);

$categoriaId->exams()->attach($idExam, [
    ['description' => 'valor de la descripcion'],
    ['iframe'      => 'contenido del iframe'],
    ['image'       => 'la imagen a guardar'],
]);
```

Lo que hacemos en este ejemplo es:

- Obtener la llave primaria de la categoria y del examen en 2 variables
- En la variable que contiene el id de la categoría le encadenamos el nombre de la relación definida en el modelo `Category` llamada `exams`
- Usamos el método `attach` donde el primer argumento será la llave primaria de la entidad  `exams`
- Posterior para lograr almacenar los valores extra en la tabla pivote, pasamos una matriz de datos

> No tienes la necesidad de utilizar dos métodos `attach` puesto que al tener las relaciones declaradas en cada modelo e invocar el nombre de la relación tomará el ID de una entidad le hará un *attatch* del ID de la segunda entidad y opcionalmente le puedes pasar valores extra que requiera tu tabla pivote.

Comment: Disculpa que te conteste hasta ahora. Acabo de revisar la pregunta y la respuesta, al parecer puse mal uno de los modelos (agregue el de User, en vez de Exam). Con ese examen, esto no cambia el sentido de la respuesta?

Comment: No te entiendo explica mejor por favor que tiene que ver Users en la duda expuesta ?

Comment: Me refiero a que había puesto User en vez de Exam en el modelo, es por ello que acabo de actualizar esa parte de la pregunta.

Comment: Estuve leyendo la doc de laravel (con respecto a las relaciones) y las lagunas que tenia se han disipado. Lo que debi haberte dicho es lo siguiente: El examen tiene muchas preguntas, estas preguntas pertenecen  a un examen. Las Preguntas, pertenecen a una sola categoria, Y las categorias tienen muchas preguntas. Sin embargo, a la hora de agregar las preguntas al examen, estas ya van relacionadas con la categoria. Es decir, la pregunta ya tiene el id de la categoria.

Comment: Ya edite la pregunta (en el UPDATE 2) lo que necesito es lo mismo (que, a la hora de insertar la pregunta, el campo exam_id sea insertado y también el campo category_id)